# Reference workbook not in collection

Tags: excel, vba

So i have 2 windows/excel opened. my code is written in for example `workbook1` in reference to `workbook2`. However in the developer mode `workbook2` isnt showing up in the properties.

Is there a way i could reference `workbook2`? I've tried the `workbooks("workbook2").activate` but it wont recognize workbook is open because its not in the properties window of the opened workbooks.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!*  Your question is a little unclear. Please check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) as well as '[ask]' and **how to create a [mcve]**.  Also [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) is a handy checklist from the site's top user.  You can [edit] your question to provide more information so that others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow!

Maybe you opened another instance of Excel. Try to close one of the workbooks and then open it again with the File/Open command from the other Workbook. Maybe this helps.

Kind Regards
Nirostar